# TSQL calculate percentage

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of customers in a SQL Server database for a health club.
The customers are listed with the date they joined and the number of times they have renewed 
I want to be able to calculate the percentage rate of customers that renewed. Any ideas on how I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: How do you know they didn't?  An expiration date per customer?  Or are all memberships the same length, e.g. one month?  Do you care if their membership has been discontinuous?

Comment: @invert does that make the question any less valid?

Answer (score 5):

If there's a table `subscriptions` with only one row per user, that gets updated with a bit `isrenewed`:

```
 SELECT 
    SUM(SIGN(isrenewed)) * 100 / COUNT(*) 
    AS Percentage
    FROM subscriptions
```

Outputs

```
 Percentage
 ---------------
 66,666666
```

If you want to round the expression you can cast it as an int

```
 SELECT 
    CAST(
      SUM(SIGN(isrenewed)) * 100 / COUNT(*) 
      AS int)
    AS Percentage
    FROM subscriptions
```

Outputs

```
 Percentage
 ---------------
 66
```

If you had a table `subscriptions` with user-specific column `userid` where having two rows would mean the subscription was renewed:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) OVER() 
    FROM subscriptions
    GROUP BY userid
    having COUNT(*) > 1) 
  * 100 / COUNT(*) AS Percentage
  FROM subscriptions
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Jan doing the method with the subquery is going to be easier than the first post.  There aren't 2 entries for when they renew. There is a field that says renewed and lists the number of times the customer has renewed. Would I still be able to use your method ? Thanks.

Comment: Updated my answer for that case, it's the second one.

Comment: thanks. I am coming up with a number that doesn't make sense. I am going to have to do more research into this.

Comment: Updated with a new version for a bit field, that uses just one table expression.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for

```
Declare @t table(Id Int Identity,CustomerName Varchar(50),DOJ Datetime,IsRenewed bit)
Insert Into @t Values('Name1','1/1/2012',1),('Name2','10/1/2012',1),('Name3','10/2/2012',0)

Select PercentageCustomerRenewed = 
Cast((Count(*) * 100) / (Select Count(*) From @t ) AS Numeric(10,2))  
From @t 
where IsRenewed = 1
```

**Result**

```
PercentageCustomerRenewed
66.00
```

Comment: Could you please post a sample data and expected outout ..so that you can easily get the solution

Comment: Here is what I have so far.  I can get the first part of the query working but I am having trouble combining the two select statements together properly. --Part 1: RenewalCount = the number of times --each customer renewed 
 SELECT * FROM 
 (SELECT JoinDate, RenewalCount, YEAR(getdate()) - YEAR(JoinDate)-  CASE WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) > MONTH(GETDATE())
   OR MONTH(GETDATE()) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DAY(GETDATE()) >= DAY(GETDATE())  then 0 else 1 end AS PotentialRenewal
  FROM Table)percRenewal  --Part 2    
 SELECT 100.0 * SUM(Renewal)/ SUM(PotentialRenewal)
From Table AS percRenewal